# Printing 2D array: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: c++

I wrote a functions that will take input in from a .txt file, create a 2D array, and print it out, but I keep on running into this error. I think its because I'm inserting data wrong in the loadData function, but I can't figure out where the error is, or if its even in that function specifically. Would you be able to help me trouble shoot this?
/// input.txt

```
6
X X X X X O
X O X O O X
X X O O O X
X X X O X X
X O X X O O
X X X X X X
```

///loadData, printBoard, and main function

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

using namespace std;

void loadData(char** arr, int &size);
void printBoard(char** arr, int size);

int main(){
    char** board;
    int size;
    loadData(board, size);
    printBoard(board, size);
    return 0;
}

void loadData(char** arr, int &size)
{
    int matrixSize;
    fstream file("input.txt", ios::in);

    //error message if file could not be opened
    if (!file){
        cout << "File could no be opened!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    file >> matrixSize;
    size = matrixSize;
    arr = new char* [matrixSize];
    //create col
    for(int i=0; i<matrixSize; ++i){
        //create row
        arr[i] = new char[matrixSize];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<matrixSize; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<matrixSize; ++j){
            file >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    file.close();
}

void printBoard(char** arr, int size){
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<size; ++j){
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" "; //WHERE ERROR OCCURS Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forget one very important thing: Arguments, even pointers, are by default passed *by value*. You do know about references, as you use it for the `size` argument to the `loadData` function, I recommend you think more about the reason you use a reference for the `size` argument, and if there's a way to solve your problem using references.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude got it, thanks!